# /sbin/ldconfig.real can't find config file

Tags: boot

Here's the boot message: `/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf: No such file or directory`. But

```
# ls -ld /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Jan  6  2018 /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf -> /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf
# ls -ld /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 Aug 23 11:23 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhybris-egl/ld.so.conf
# ls -ld /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhybris-egl/ld.so.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 40 Mar  7  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhybris-egl/ld.so.conf
```

Any hints on removing this warning will be gratefully received.